# PHP: Creating a reset password system

Tags: php, passwords

I'm creating a password reset system from scratch, and I have a few questions.

I know I could have googled this, but they really don't go into detail on the parts I want to know more about. I know how to code one, and I know how one works, but I still don't understand certain parts.

Here is what I have so far.

- A user requests a password reset
- The code sends an email, containing a token, but that token expires after X minutes.
- The user clicks the link in the email, and the page validates the token if it's valid it changes the password to whatever the user chooses for their new password.

What I don't understand is, what happens if the user doesn't respond to the email but requests another one, then they go to the first one and click it? what happens to the second one?

Does it just check if the token matches and doesn't worry about the other ones as they'll expire anyway? Are the older ones still usable when a newer one has been used?

Can someone shine any light on this for me please? Also, how long should a password reset code be valid for?

Comment: You decide what happens, and you decide how long they should be valid. If you insert the token into the users row in the user table then the user will only be able to use the last issued token as any older will be overwritten and invalidated. If you create a new table for tokens (and link it to the users table with a foreign key to the user id) then one user can have multiple valid tokens.

Comment: Thank you, but I am more asking of "which is the best way to do it?", the two methods you mentioned, but also should I just make all past tokens invalid when generating a new one?

Comment: Sadly there very rarely is a "best way to do it". You need to figure out how you want your system to function and then either one can be the best way to do it. I hate it when systems invalidate all tokens but the last one. Especially annoying if the site says the token is valid for 24 hours but a slow email or similar results in asking for multiple tokens -> not getting a token that works.

Comment: The question IMHO is too broad/opinion-based.